# Django / Paypal - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'supportOneTouchLoginOn8ball' of null

Tags: django, paypal

I am getting the error bellow when I click the button to go the paypal page, the error goes to console. the page shows a loop with the text:

Securely logging you in...

You activated PayPal One Touch™, so no need to enter your password today.

It stays here permanently.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'supportOneTouchLoginOn8ball' of null
    at hermes?token=96N01477KD7295421&useraction=commit&mfid=1557861060485_15a0fd2aec52d:1
    at hermes?token=96N01477KD7295421&useraction=commit&mfid=1557861060485_15a0fd2aec52d:1
    at hermes?token=96N01477KD7295421&useraction=commit&mfid=1557861060485_15a0fd2aec52d:1
(anonymous) @ hermes?token=96N01477KD7295421&useraction=commit&mfid=1557861060485_15a0fd2aec52d:1
(anonymous) @ hermes?token=96N01477KD7295421&useraction=commit&mfid=1557861060485_15a0fd2aec52d:1
(anonymous) @ hermes?token=96N01477KD7295421&useraction=commit&mfid=1557861060485_15a0fd2aec52d:1
```

It started with chrome, then in firefox and edge.
Everything was working correctly two days ago,

It works in safari in my phone, so I suspect it might have something to do with my computer,

How can I overcome this?

Comment: I´m facing the same problem, but it´s happening in mobile phones with Android. So I assume that it´s not a problem with your computer or the mobile phones where I´m testing it.

Comment: interesting! I've tried incognito mode in chrome and it works like that, so maybe is something related to browser automatic info, let me know if you get something new please